QuickFix/Go with Coinbase Exchange LOGON conundrum
Since updated the 2nd paragraph to clarify the LOGON sequence details as pointed out in one of the comments below
I'm relatively new to FIX and I'm spiking the use of QuickFix/Go to manage FIX sessions with Coinbase Exchange.  These are long lasting sessions.  ResetOnLogon, ResetOnDisconnect, and ResetOnLogout configuration settings are all set to 'N' so that interrupted sessions will pick up where they left off barring the mandatory Logout by Coinbase at 1PM ET every Saturday.
Coinbase's LOGON response will always return MsgSeqNum = 1 regardless of ResetSeqNumFlag=N in the LOGON request from us. This is fine for the first LOGON of a session as 1 is the expected target message sequence number for our initiator.  However, if I stop the session  and restart QuickFIX/Go rejects the LOGON response received from Coinbase saying the message number is too low, which seems correct but keeps the session from being established.
The only way I've been able to get around this is to manually set the next target message sequence number in the FromAdmin handler before QuickFix/Go attempts to validate sequence nubmers:
func (a *App) FromAdmin(msg *quickfix.Message, sessionID quickfix.SessionID) (reject quickfix.MessageRejectError) {
    if msg.IsMsgTypeOf(string(enum.MsgType_LOGON)) {

        // THIS FEELS WRONG
        msgNum, _ := msg.Header.GetInt(tag.MsgSeqNum)
        _ = quickfix.SetNextTargetMsgSeqNum(sessionID, msgNum)


    } else if msg.IsMsgTypeOf(string(enum.MsgType_SEQUENCE_RESET)) && !msg.Header.Has(tag.PossDupFlag) {

        // SHOULD I BE CHECKING AGAINST THE INITIAL SEQ NUMBERS MYSELF HERE???

    } else {
        fmt.Println("FromAdmin: Received Admin message", msg.String())
    }
    return
}

After that, Coinbase seems to  honor the ResetSeqNumFlag=N flag of this second successful (albeit forced on my end) LOGON with a SequenceReset to the target sequence number from the previous session, which QuickFIX/Go happily accepts and the session moves along.
I feel fairly certain that I shouldn't naively reset the TSN to 1 just to satisfy the LOGON sequence mandated by the exchange. I'm also unsure how to properly tell QuickFIX/Go what the TSN actually should be during/after the sequence reset callback, such that gap detection can kick in.
Is QuickFIX/Go just not compatible with Coinbase's setup?
I've included some logs of this below.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.
Initial Session humming along with a couple heartbeats and a logon
.
.
.
2024/11/19 04:25:15.329915 8=FIXT.1.1|9=101|35=0|49=Coinbase|56=myuser|34=11|50=TEST|52=20241119-04:25:15.433499|369=9|10=047|
2024/11/19 04:25:17.380701 8=FIXT.1.1|9=84|35=0|34=10|49=myuser|52=20241119-04:25:17.363|56=Coinbase|10=106|

Simulated network outage via wifi disconnect so my initiator tries a TEST request

2024/11/19 04:25:27.356721 8=FIXT.1.1|9=93|35=1|34=11|49=myuser|52=20241119-04:25:27.337|56=Coinbase|112=TEST|10=128|

network comes back up we LOGON again; The acceptor's response is accepted by the QuickFix/Go initiator but only because of my forced target number change in the FromAdmin handler
without it we would get the message too low error

2024/11/19 04:27:39.715256 8=FIXT.1.1|9=216|35=A|34=12|49=myuser|52=20241119-04:27:39.695|56=Coinbase|95=44|96=yRsmjXXh4DFH4CKX7dpR/0eG1x3/YYJbQsZ8AMuzpzg=|98=0|108=10|141=N|553=myuser|554=mypassword|1137=9|10=020|
2024/11/19 04:27:39.793277 8=FIXT.1.1|9=126|35=A|49=Coinbase|56=myuser|34=1|50=TEST|52=20241119-04:27:39.893965|369=12|98=0|108=10|141=N|1137=9|10=204|

acceptor immediately sends a sequence reset to 16, a test request, the QuickFix/Go initiator updates the sequence number to 16 and then more heartbeating

2024/11/19 04:27:39.806345 8=FIXT.1.1|9=113|35=4|49=Coinbase|56=myuser|34=2|50=TEST|52=20241119-04:27:39.897364|369=12|123=Y|36=16|10=120|

2024/11/19 04:27:48.834779 8=FIXT.1.1|9=102|35=0|49=Coinbase|56=myuser|34=16|50=TEST|52=20241119-04:27:48.935898|369=12|10=113|
2024/11/19 04:27:49.740027 8=FIXT.1.1|9=84|35=0|34=13|49=myuser|52=20241119-04:27:49.725|56=Coinbase|10=118|
2024/11/19 04:27:57.835079 8=FIXT.1.1|9=102|35=0|49=Coinbase|56=myuser|34=17|50=TEST|52=20241119-04:27:57.936187|369=13|10=107|
2024/11/19 04:27:59.761167 8=FIXT.1.1|9=84|35=0|34=14|49=myuser|52=20241119-04:27:59.740|56=Coinbase|10=117|
2024/11/19 04:28:06.845546 8=FIXT.1.1|9=102|35=0|49=Coinbase|56=myuser|34=18|50=TEST|52=20241119-04:28:06.936317|369=14|10=099|
2024/11/19 04:28:09.780998 8=FIXT.1.1|9=84|35=0|34=15|49=myuser|52=20241119-04:28:09.762|56=Coinbase|10=118|
2024/11/19 04:28:15.836470 8=FIXT.1.1|9=102|35=0|49=Coinbase|56=myuser|34=19|50=TEST|52=20241119-04:28:15.936565|369=15|10=106|
2024/11/19 04:28:19.798929 8=FIXT.1.1|9=84|35=0|34=16|49=myuser|52=20241119-04:28:19.782|56=Coinbase|10=122|
2024/11/19 04:28:19.836487 8=FIXT.1.1|9=112|35=1|49=Coinbase|56=myuser|34=20|50=TEST|52=20241119-04:28:19.936558|369=15|112=12345|10=059|
2024/11/19 04:28:19.852480 8=FIXT.1.1|9=94|35=0|34=17|49=myuser|52=20241119-04:28:19.836|56=Coinbase|112=12345|10=077|


(1) You say "Coinbase stipulates that the MsgSeqNum (34) must be set to 1 for both sides of the connection on LOGON." but then you describe a situation where this isn't true.  Which is it?  (2) Are you using a persistent StoreFactory, such as FileStoreFactory, so that you can maintain seq nums between disconnects?

Also, didn't you post a similar question before?  I'm having deja vu, but I can't find it.

@GrantBirchmeier Their documentation does state that "MsgSeqNum always equals 1 (34=1) on this message in both directions" but I've since learned that their acceptor will accept the LOGON on their side as long as the MsgSeqNum component of the signature is "1".   So yes, in the logs above you can see that on the second LOGON i'm sending 34=12.  The issue is that their LOGON response will always be set to 1 regardless of 141=N.  QuickFix/Go will reject that because will be expecting a higher number from the previous session.  Thus, my SetNextTargetMsgSeqNum hack.  I'm using a FileStoreFactory

@GrantBirchmeier I did post a similar question a couple days ago but after reflecting on it I realized it didn't get to the heart of the issue which I hope I've done better here.

If you are describing the situation accurately, then it sounds like they have made a mistake.  If you send 141=Y, then they should respond with 34=1.  And of course, their docs are clearly inconsistent with what you are seeing.  I think you should reach out to their support.

I will indeed.  Thanks for your confirmation that what I'm seeing isn't typical.
